# DELETE Command taking a lot of time with clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I don't have large amount of data in my table. it contains only 16000 records. I want to delete around 33 records from this table which is taking 9-10 seconds. Below is the schema of the table and Query that I am trying for deletion. Please check and let me know the reason and solution for this.

I am sharing the execution plan image also for the reference:

[image]

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Report]
(
    [ReportId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WorkId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GeneratedOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
    [CGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [EGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Document] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SessionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Report] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ReportId] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Report] 
    ADD DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()) FOR [CreatedDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Report] 
    ADD DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()) FOR [UpdatedDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Report] 
    ADD DEFAULT ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') FOR [SessionId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Report] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Report_Work_WorkId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([WorkId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Work] ([WorkId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Report] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Report_Work_WorkId]
GO
```

Query:

```
-- This select query is executing faster and completed in 1 second
SELECT r.ReportId   
INTO #ReportIds
FROM dbo.Report r  
JOIN dbo.Work w ON r.WorkId = w.WorkId AND w.TimePeriodId = 2 
WHERE r.[Type] = 'BalanceReport'

-- This delete query is taking 9-10 seconds to delete 33 records.
DELETE r  
FROM dbo.Report r  
WHERE r.ReportId IN (SELECT ReportId FROM #ReportIds)
```

Comment: Why are you using a temp table, what happens if you just turn the first query into a delete? Are you the only process or is there concurrency going on? Have you looked at what may be blocking?

Comment: I am executing this manually (no concurrency) and If I remove that temp table and append first query to the delete one, still it takes the same time. no performance improvement.

Comment: I'm no big fan of IN (subquery). use inner join. Maybe it won't help but still

Comment: @siggemannen - I did try inner join in delete query but no luck.

Comment: can you include output of: set statistics io on <your delete> set statistics in off

Comment: your query shouldn't take that long normally, so something else might be going on

Comment: Your query is either being blocked or is waiting on a resource. Are there any triggers on the table? Is it system versioned? Anything else that is non-standard?

Comment: Can you upload the XML for the actual execution plan corresponding to that image (or a similar run) to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that this query is the one causing the slowness given you have another three in the batch. Please share the full execution plan for all queries via the above link. If you want to anonymize it you can use SentryOne Plan Explorer. Please also show the table definition for `dbo.Work`.

Comment: Did you check the runtime with and exists and inner JOIN instead of in ?
Try to use navarchar max ,it only when you need it. I don't think it's necessary here

Comment: @Charlieface - It is definitely that statement. The time elapsed by the "Clustered Index Delete" operator shows as 9 seconds. 

By the way I tested the trigger theory and that doesn't inflate the elapsed timings of that operator. The execution plan will have wait stats info that will likely be informative

Comment: @siggemannen I doubt `exists` `in` and `join` will make any difference, they will all result in the same plan most likely. SQL Server is perfectly capable of transforming between them.

Comment: And the part of the plan that was taking the time was only the delete operator. Not identifying the rows to delete. I assume likely there are S locks blocking the conversion of U lock to an X lock

Comment: @siggemannen, Charlieface, MartinSmith - I have uploaded query plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByfgX7F73

Comment: @Charlieface, it has made a difference in my exp, esp. exists. Maybe not in all cases, but sometimes sql server doesn't choose the best. But of course, one has some bias due to working with specific styles over the years as well.

Comment: So `LOG_RATE_GOVERNOR` is actually the main wait. Is this on Azure? What SKU? Also what size are the `Document` that you are deleting?

Comment: And what are the definitions of `IX_Report_WorkId_Type, IX_Report_WorkId__GeneratedOn`? including any included columns?

Comment: Assuming the `Document` are pretty huge maybe you could come up with a scheme where you store them in a partitioned table - partitioned in a way that is amenable to your delete patterns and just soft delete them and then truncate the partitions when they are logically empty to reduce logging overhead of removing them

Comment: Could you update .WRITE() the Document before the deletion? `update dbo.Report
set Document.write('', 0, null)
where Document is not null
and ReportId in ..#ReportIds`